# Authenticate Generated API Key in accessing Django Rest API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to let third-party users access some of the REST APIs that I have. I made an `APIkey` model that will store the generated keys that can be used in accessing the API.

I just don't know yet how will I add the API key to the authentication of my app since I already have a `BearerTokenAuthentication` in my `auth.py`

Answer (score 1):

Typically in Django, authentication corresponds to a specific *user*, whereas an API-key may identify a *client app*, or other user agent. You *may* decide to hand out a unique API-key to each user - in which case it is just another way of authenticating the user - but you can typically assign an API-key to an app, or even a 3rd party organisation/system. One of your APIs may have the requirement to identify the user and client app, in which case you need both user authentication and API-key. Another API may only need to know the client app, in which case only the API-key is sufficient.

An API-key is typically passed as the "**x-api-key**" HTTP header. You must retrieve this header in your view and look up the model instance of APIkey.

Comment: In auth.py, is it possible to have both the `BearerTokenAuthentication` and the `ApiKeyTokenAuthentication`? That's where I'll be validation the token right?

Comment: At first glance, it seems the obvious route to go, but the problem is that the API-key does not identify an individual user, rather a client app/system/organisation, so you can't wrap the checking of the API-key as a Django authenticator: the latter must always return a User instance if successfully authenticated. Rather, you want to create a Django *permission* representing the API-key. But it's better to use an existing solution like: https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/